# How do I use Node.insertBefore to add content to a specific node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a string variable as a child of a node. The code that I'm using looks like this

```
$(this).parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore('content',$(this).parentNode)
```

I believe that this is correct syntax, but I keep receiving NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Instead of using a literal string 'content', maybe you have to use `createTextNode('content')` and pass it the created node as in this example: http://javascript.about.com/library/bldom12.htm

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with RoR, so I may be wrong, but is that a combination of jQuery and plain JavaScript that you're using?

Comment: @Ryan Kinal:  That's correct.  The question has no ROR code, but maybe there's an applicable ROR trick? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parentElement.insertBefore(el, beforeWhat);
```

if you want to insert a new element BEFORE a node

if you want to append a new textNode to the element you rather need

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("content");
el.appendChild(textNode);
```

but what really bothers me is that you seem to using jQuery or some framework, and use DOM methods on them. Because that won't work.

You need to use their own methods then, like:

```
$(this).append("content");
```

Comment: I was too quick to call you out, I apologize for that. It turned out that prototype was overriding the $() operator so when I thought I was using jQuery, it was actually prototype which is why non of the methods I tried were working. To use the two together I put  var $j = jQuery.noConflict()  at the top of my application.js file

Comment: Yeah my instinct was somewhat right then. Glad you've solved it. :)